# Modifying preloaded pages with JQueryMobile and PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an application with jqm and phonegap. The application consists of multiple html pages that will be updated based on information returned from a web server.

My initial plan was to retrieve all the information from the web server the first time the application loads and pre-populate the other html pages so that the user doesn't have to wait to contact the server as they navigating between each page.

```
function onDeviceReady() {

// pre-fetch pages so we can setup the main pages before the user gets to them
$.mobile.loadPage( "page2.html", { showLoadMsg: false } );
$.mobile.loadPage( "page3.html", { showLoadMsg: false } );


// Return JSON from php web server
    ....

// id of div on page2.html - update based on information returned from web server
$("#page2MainDiv").append('<p>hello!!!</p>');
```

}

I have two questions:

1) The above code isn't working...I don't get any errors but the html doesn't update - I can't see where I'm going wrong and it's driving me crazy!

2) Is this a sensible approach? As I'm new to mobile and web development I am not sure if there is a better approach.

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it easier. Instead of javascript, you may use simple "data-prefetch" attribute to links. Try to read this: [JQuery Mobile Cahce & Prefetch](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html). Loading pages may be a good idea, if you don't have a lot of data and subpages. Usually you don't know what subpage will user choose, or if he will choose any. In this case loading most, or even all data may be pointless. Again, if your app is small and does not require lot of data, you may use your approch. However I don't suggest it and don't use it in my apps. Loading data may be also expensive for the user, remember about this.